# Event when data has been written to stream?

Tags: c#, events, filestream

I'm trying to create a program which invokes an action as soon as new data has been written to a FileStream object. My current approach is as follows:

```
public class BlockingFileStream : FileStream
{

    public override int Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count)
    {
        while (Position == Length) ;
        return base.Read(array, offset, count);
    }

    public override int ReadByte()
    {
        while (Position == Length) ;
        return base.ReadByte();
    }

}
```

As you can see, all this class does is wait until the stream's length is larger than its current position. It seems to be working, however, I've been wondering if there is any better way of doing this. So my question is:

Is there a better way of doing what is done in the code snipped posted above?

Comment: Is your program writing to the stream, or is another program writing to the file while you spin-wait on checking the file size?

Comment: Another program is accessing the file at the same time whilst I want to keep checking whether new data has been written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to see if that would be a better solution for you. Busy waiting is usually not a good solution.

Comment: +1 for understatement: "Busy waiting is usually not a good solution"

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I think you should not keep the file in "opened" state because another program could not write data to the file.

Try using the [`FileSystemWatcher` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) instead to receive notification about file changes ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Comment: It is not true that “another program could not write data to the file.” It is possible to pass arguments to `File.Open` that indicate that the file access can be shared.